# Bash: update specific part of a file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a makefile (Makefile.inc) which lists .c files present in a directory.

```
#                                                                                                                                                                                  
# Makefile.inc                                                                                                                                  
#                                                                                                                                                                                        

..
unknown number of lines
..                                                                                                                                                            

LIB_FOO_BAR_SRCS = \                                                                                                                                                               
    a.c \                                                                                                                                                                           
    f.c \                                                                                                                                                                      
    k.c \                                                                                                                                                                           
    m.c \                                                                                                                                                                            
    z.c        
..
unknown number of lines
..
```

I want to write a short script, which will update Makefile.inc with new .c files every time I run it. Input to the script will be location of the sources and Makefile.inc.

Example:
After adding s.c and b.c to the source directory and running the script, Makefile.inc should be updated from the one mentioned above to the one below:

```
#                                                                                                                                                                                  
# Makefile.inc                                                                                                                                  
#                                                                                                                                                                                        

..
unknown number of lines
..                                                                                                                                                         

LIB_FOO_BAR_SRCS = \                                                                                                                                                               
    a.c \ 
    b.c \                                                                                                                                                                          
    f.c \                                                                                                                                                                      
    k.c \                                                                                                                                                                           
    m.c \
    s.c \                                                                                                                                                                            
    z.c        

..
unknown number of lines
..
```

Few conditions:

1. List of .c files in Makefile.inc should be sorted
2. Line number for LIB_FOO_BAR_SRCS is not known. However, the variable LIB_FOO_BAR_SRCS definitely starts with "LIB_" and ends with "_SRCS".
3. Script should be generic as I am planning to use this for huge number of Makefiles.

I have figured out a way to grep for _SRCS and get the line number.
I have also formatted the list to be added.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                              
TAB=$'\t'                                                                                                                                                                                

MAKEFILE_PATH="PATH/TO/Makefile.inc"                                               
SRC_PATH="PATH/TO/FOO_BAR/SRC"                                                             

Line=$(grep -n -m 1 "SRCS" $MAKEFILE_PATH  | cut -f1 -d: | sort)                                                                                                                               
echo $Line                                                                                                                                                                               

list_src=$(ls -p "$SRC_PATH"/*.c | xargs -n1 basename | sed "s/^/${TAB}/" | sed 's/$/ \\/' | sed '$ s/.$//')
echo $list_src
```

Output:

```
15
        a.c \ 
        b.c \                                                                                                                                                                          
        f.c \                                                                                                                                                                      
        k.c \                                                                                                                                                                           
        m.c \
        s.c \                                                                                                                                                                            
        z.c
```

Now, the hard part. How to remove the existing list after line number $Line and append the new list ($list_src)?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v nl="${newlist}" '!f; $1~/^LIB_.*_SRCS$/{f=1; print nl} !NF{f=0}' file
```

will replace the lines between the pattern `LIB_.*_SRCS` to empty line with the given argument.

Comment: Works but, there is a problem. The file names are now displayed in one line (space separated). How to make it display in new lines as in the original file?